# Issue with accessing different types of variable values in cplex solution pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, cplex, docplex

I have this MILP model that I am solving by cplex python API:

```
def CModel():
    
 mdl=Model('Generate')

#variable declaration
        y=mdl.binary_var_dict(ijk,name='y')
        Sum=mdl.integer_var_dict(ij,name='S')
#objective
        mdl.minimize(0)

#constraints
        #1
        mdl.add_constraints(mdl.sum(y[(i,j,k)]+y[(j,i,k)] for j in T)==1 for i in T for k in K)
        #2

        mdl.add_constraints(mdl.sum(y[(i,j,k)]+y[(j,i,k)] for k in K1 )==1 for i in T for j in T if i!=j)
        #3

        mdl.add_constraints(mdl.sum(y[(i,j,k)]+y[(j,i,k)] for k in K2 )==1 for i in T for j in T if i!=j)
        #4

        mdl.add_constraints(mdl.sum(y[(i,j,k)] for k in K )==1 for i in T for j in T if i!=j)
        #5     
        for i,j in ij:
            for k in K4:
                Sum=mdl.sum(y[(j,i,k1)] for k1 in range(k+1,k+8 ))
                mdl.add(mdl.if_then(y[(i,j,k)]==1, Sum==0))
 return mdl
```

Sum is a variable that I am using to make the 5th constraint (I'm just using it to restrict y on certain ranges to 0). In the solution pool I just need the indices of y where y==1. I have this solution pool for solving the model:

```
def soln_pool(mdl):
    cpx = mdl.get_cplex()
    cpx.parameters.parallel.set(1)
    cpx.parameters.mip.pool.intensity.set(4)
    cpx.populatelim=50
    st2=time.time()
    try:
        cpx.populate_solution_pool()
    except CplexSolverError:
        print("Exception raised during populate")
        return []
    numsol = cpx.solution.pool.get_num() #max timing by 29 second
    sol_pool = []
    pool=[]
    pool2=[]

    if numsol!=0:
        for i in range(numsol):
            indices = [j for j, a in enumerate(cpx.solution.pool.get_values(i)) if a > 0.5]  

        for element in sol_pool:
              
                for j in element:
                        v = mdl.get_var_by_index(j)                        
                        i1 = int(v.name.split('_')[1])
                        i2 = int(v.name.split('_')[2])
                        i3 = int(v.name.split('_')[3])
                        pool.append([i1,i2,i3])
                pool2.append(pool)
```

Before I add constriant #5 there was no problem with the solution pool function but after adding #5 I get this error:

```
    i1 = int(v.name.split('_')[1])

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '{y'
```

Hiw can I access only variable y values on solution pool and convert then to integers?

Answer (score 0):

You can just check `v.name.startswith('y')` to filter out anything that is not a plain y variable. My guess is that the offending variable is some auxiliary variable that was created under the hood. You could print the full `v.name` to see the name of the offending variable's name. If it is an autocreated variable then its name will tell for which constraint it was created.

Also note that you have

```
Sum=mdl.integer_var_dict(ij,name='S')
```

and later

```
Sum=mdl.sum(y[(j,i,k1)] for k1 in range(k+1,k+8 ))
```

The latter overwrites the former. That is probably not what you intend to do.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel is right. `Model.if_then` generates a boolean variable. You can check this with this small code:

```
def is_gen(dv):
    return 'yes' if dv.is_generated() else 'no'
for dv in cm.iter_variables():
    print(f'-- variable: {dv.name}, index={dv.index}, generated={is_gen(dv)}')
```

which generates output like:

```
-- variable: _bool{y_10_2_3 == 1}, index=5887, generated=yes
```

which represents the truth variable for constraint y_20_2_3==1.

As you can see, calling `is_generated()` on a variable return True when the variable has been generated by Docplex, so you can just filter out those variables in you split code.